# Changing variable by method

Tags: java

Why am I getting an output equals 5? I was expecting 6, because after the "addthenumber(x);" line, the method is called, and what I am thinking is the method performs the calculation and 5 becomes 6. So sysout should print 6, but how is it 5?

```
public class CodeMomkeyPassingvalue 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int x = 5;
        addthenumber(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    private static void addthenumber(int number) 
    {
        number = number+1;
    }
}
```

output:

```
5
```

Comment: The technical explanation to why is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Because 5 is passed to the function, not x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code

```
 {

        int x = 5; // declare x = 5 here

        addthenumber(x); // calling function, passing 5
```

`catch is here` - Arguments are **passed by value, not by reference**. x itself is not passed, only the value of the x is passed to the method.

```
        System.out.println(x); // printing same x value here, ie 5

    }
```

private static void addthenumber(int number) {

```
    number = number + 1;  // 1 added to number locally, and is referencing inside method only.


}
```

Comment: Thanks to all three for clearing it up for me.Now I understand the concept. I was confused because, earlier I was told that the value of a variable "can" change in the flow of a program when the same variable is assigned a different value later.

Answer (score 6):

Arguments to methods are passed **by value**, not by reference. That means that not the variable itself, but only the value of the variable is passed to the method.

The variable `number` inside the method `addthenumber` is not the same variable as the variable `x` in the `main` method. When you change the value of `number`, it does not have any effect on the variable `x` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Java follows the `call by value` paradigma, so the value is not changed in the calling function. If you would like to change the value you have to return it after adding 1;

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int x = 5;
     x = addthenumber(x);
    System.out.println(x);
}

private static int addthenumber(int number) 
{
    return number+1;
}
```